# Para utilizar datepicker en Symfony 3 conocen algun Bundle?

Tags: jquery, symfony3, jquery-ui

En proyectos anteriores utilice el Bundle Genemu y funcionaba bien ahora para esta version de symfony me presenta problemas, aqui deje el issue que todavia no tiene respuesta: https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle/issues/441

Alguien trabaja con algun Bundle para conseguir que trabaje con los efectos de jquery?

Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigando, encontré la solución a este problema. Lo resolví utilizando el Bundle:

https://github.com/stephanecollot/DatetimepickerBundle

Es un Bundle que soporta Symfony 3.2.x y tiene muy buena documentación

El código final que muestra en el formulario el calendario como quería es este:

```
<?php
// ...
use SC\DatetimepickerBundle\Form\Type\DatetimeType;

public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
$builder

    // full options
    ->add('date', DatetimeType::class, array( 'pickerOptions' =>
        array('format' => 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            'weekStart' => 0,
            'startDate' => date('m/d/Y'), 
            'autoclose' => true,
            'startView' => 'month',
            'minView' => 'month',
            'maxView' => 'decade',
            'todayBtn' => false,
            'todayHighlight' => false,
            'keyboardNavigation' => true,
            'language' => 'es',
            'forceParse' => true,
            'showMeridian' => false,
            ))) ; 

}
```

Saludos